# Change windows shell

Tags: windows, shell

I have asus Rog ally and want to get console experience like steam deck but unfortunately windows gui isn't support this at all.

I don't want to see any login or desktop screen at boot.

I heard that we can replace windows11 shell (explorer.exe) with any app.
I want to replace it with steam big picture and at same time can access other windows apps and functions.
Is there a complete guide for this?

Comment: The steps in this guide look like they should still work for windows 11: https://steamcommunity.com/groups/bigpicture/discussions/1/864958451556578063/ but read through the comments for some alternatives, and make sure you understand how to change it back

Comment: Thanks
It looks complicated and miss with windows essential files.

Comment: Can we start steam before login and desktop appearing? to avoid touching windows files

Answer (score 2):

Going from the [linked guide](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/bigpicture/discussions/1/864958451556578063/), there are three steps:

1. Set steam to launch in big picture mode
2. Set steam as your windows shell (making it run instead of the desktop):

   - open regedit and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
   - Make a new string entry with Name=`Shell`, and Value=`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"`
3. Set windows to log in automatically, skipping the logon screen:

   - I recommend using the Microsoft tool [AutoLogon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) to configure this automatically instead of following the guide instructions.
   - Otherwise, the longer manual process can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon

---

To start the normal windows desktop: `ctrl`+`alt`+`del` > Task Manager > File > Run new task > explorer

To undo the shell change permanently, use regedit to delete the Shell value you created before, and reboot