# Hide & disable Windows 10 taskbar at all

Tags: windows, taskbar, kiosk

I need to launch Windows but with taskbar hidden at all, not just the auto-hide option but totally hidden, without the possibility to show it with the mouse. It needs to be the default behavior **at the very moment** the user logon.

The final goal is like a kiosk mode, where user can only use one application and cannot launch other applications from Start button. But with the possibility to fall back to Windows if the main application is closed.

Comment: Why not use actual Kiosk Mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: “But with the possibility to fall back to Windows if the main application is closed.” - This isn’t possible with any current Kiosk software or Kisok mode

Comment: You could change the windows Shell to launch different application from explorer.exe, which is fairly similar to what the real kiosk mode does. From there, you can still do: ctrl+alt+del > task manager > run > explorer.exe, to load the taskbar/regular windows. Check out the answer here for more details: https://superuser.com/a/1805786/673426

Comment: You could implement this by setting Taskbar size to zero or one pixel for the ersatz kiosk mode using the Registry, and keeping .reg files for both reduced height (or width) and normal. To enable or disable the taskbar, import the appropriate file. You'd need to diff the Registry, before and after setting Taskbar size,  to find where this value is stored.

Comment: @spikey_richie I cannot use kiosk mode because I've to run an HMI application, and some functionalities comes through third part applications.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm looking for a generic configuration that doesn't change with hardware or Windows version.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale in the end your idea is the closest to my needs. I'd come to the same conclusion, and I've a launcher custom application that can suit my needs (with some changes).